# How to add a column that based on the different value for every row conducts excel type "INDEX, MATCH, MATCH" search from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, dynamic-columns

I am trying to add a column called "Yield to Worst" and that for every  row it use the "Ticker" value for that row and conducts a INDEX, MATCH, MATCH to another dataframe to find the value Yield to Worst for a particular ticker. The dataframes are below "Tickers" and "Funds_Data". The desired output as well.

**Tickers** Dataframe

```
Index   Tickers
0   IEF US Equity
1   JNK US Equity
2   HYG US Equity
3   LQD US Equity
```

**Funds_Data** Dataframe

```
         JNK US Equity  HYG US Equity   LQD US Equity   IEF US Equity
AUM      9560           16313           31525           13169
Duration 3.6            3.3             8.8             7.4
1-Mth    1.17           0.94            0.85            0.11
3-Mth    4.11           3.59            3.38            1.93
YTD      9.52           8.66            6.61            2.21
Yield    6.46           6.23            4.08            2.49
```

**Desired Output**

```
Index   Tickers    Yield
0   IEF US Equity   2.49
1   JNK US Equity   6.46
2   HYG US Equity   6.23
3   LQD US Equity   4.08
```

**Attempted Code**

```py
for ticker in range (0, len(Tickers)):
    Yield = pd.DataFrame(funds_data.loc['Yield to Worst', ticker])
Tickers['Yield'] = Yield
```

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Where do you get the data from MBB from?

Comment: `Tickers.set_index('Tickers'); Tickers['Yield'] = funds_data.loc['Yield to Worst']; Ticker.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: @EdekiOkoh .... Thanks for the fast response. Apologies I missed the last column with MBB data. The data for MBB is below, but we the concept is the same, we can ignore MBB if thats easier. MBB US Equity
AUM: 16179
Duration:5.1
1-Mth: 0.37
3-Mth: 1.62
YTD: 2.19
Yield: 2.92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `tickers` with `funds_data` taking the `Yield` row:

```
tickers.merge(funds_data.loc['Yield'],
              how='left', left_on='Tickers', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
             Tickers  Yield
Index                      
0      JNK US Equity   6.46
1      HYG US Equity   6.23
2      LQD US Equity   4.08
3      IEF US Equity   2.49
5      MBB US Equity    NaN
```

P.S. There's no data for "MBB US Equity" in your sample `funds_data`, so it comes out as `NaN`

Comment: Thank you so much @perl for the fast response. Quick question, how could I make it work when the tickers are not in the same order in both dataframes and when the tickers are in rows for onw dataframe and in the coolumns for the other dataframe? sincerely thank you for your help!

Comment: So basically `funds_data.loc['Yield']` is a series with indexes = columns of the `funds_data`, and we merge `tickers` to this series. The order does not matter in this case, and series is merged as a column, so what was columns of `funds_data` before becomes rows in this new DataFrame

Comment: You are awesome! Thank so much, that worked pretty well.